# How to delete nodes of a linked list between two indices?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have the following linked list implementation:

```
struct _node {
    char *string;
    struct _node *next;
}

struct _list {
    struct _node *head;
    struct _node *tail;
}
```

I want to make the following function:

```
void deleteList(struct _list *list, int from, int to) {
    int i;

    assert(list != NULL);

    // I skipped error checking for out of range parameters for brevity of code

    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        deleteNode(list->head, i);
    }
}
```

// I ran this function with this linked list: `[First]->[Second]->NULL`

like this `deleteNodes(list, 1, 1)` to delete the second line and got
`[First]->[Second]->NULL` but when I run it like this `deleteList(list, 0, 1)` with this input `[First]->[Second]->[Third]->NULL` I get a seg fault.

Here is my deleteNode function

```
void deleteNode(struct _node *head, int index) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int i;
    struct _node *temp = head;

    if (index == 0) {
        if (head->next == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            head = head->next;
            free(head);
            return;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; temp!=NULL && i<index-1; i++) {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    Link next = temp->next->next;

    free(temp->next);

    temp->next = next;
}
```

I wrote a separate function to delete the head of the linked list if from or to = 0:

```
void pop(struct _node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    struct _node *temp = head;
    head = head->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

but it gives me seg fault or memory error Abort trapL 6.

Comment: Your loop where you call `deleteNode` has a flaw: Once you deleted the first node in the range, the next node to delete will not have the same index as before.

Comment: Of course! So I need to keep a pointer to the new head? Or should I use an entirely different approach?

Comment: A simple solution is to reverse the loop, and delete the last node in the range first, followed by the next to last, etc.

Comment: Also, i believe that in my deleteNode function, what I do with `if (index == 0)` is wrong.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok that makes sense, I thought of that but wasn't confident enough to try it.

Comment: I did a little more testing and it looks like reversing the loop works but I still can't delete a node at index 0.

Comment: btw, this sorta annoyed me `ASSERT(list != NULL)`, why bother sanity input check when not checking all input, you assume that if list would be given null you'd collapse somehow and receive segfault, how about if I call deleteList with negative number as input and somehow IOF your code.... use unsigned int or size_t to represent positive scalars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all good to use just one `struct`, a node for your purpose.

```
struct node {
    char *string;
    struct node *next;
};
```

Then your loop for removing elements between two indices will not delete the right elements if you don't adjust the index according to the changing length of the list. And you must also return the new head of the list.

```
struct node *deleteList(struct node *head, unsigned from, unsigned to) {
    unsigned i;
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        head = delete_at_index(head, i - count);
        count++;
    }
    return head;
}
```

The help function `delete_at_index` looks as follows.

```
struct node *delete_at_index(struct node *head, unsigned i) {
    struct node *next;

    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    next = head->next;

    return i == 0
           ? (free(head), next)                                 /* If i == 0, the first element needs to die. Do it. */
           : (head->next = delete_at_index(next, i -
                                                 1), head); /* If it isn't the first element, we recursively check the rest. */
}
```

Complete program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *string;
    struct node *next;
};

void freeList(struct node *head) {
    struct node *tmp;

    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp->string);
        free(tmp);
    }

}

struct node *delete_at_index(struct node *head, unsigned i) {
    struct node *next;

    if (head == NULL)
        return head;

    next = head->next;

    return i == 0
           ? (free(head), next)                                 /* If i == 0, the first element needs to die. Do it. */
           : (head->next = delete_at_index(next, i -
                                                 1), head); /* If it isn't the first element, we recursively check the rest. */
}

struct node *deleteList(struct node *head, unsigned from, unsigned to) {
    unsigned i;
    unsigned count = 0;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++) {
        head = delete_at_index(head, i - count);
        count++;
    }
    return head;
}

void pushvar1(struct node **head_ref, char *new_data) {
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->string = strdup(new_data);
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}

void printListvar1(struct node *node) {
    while (node != NULL) {
        printf(" %s ", node->string);
        node = node->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct node *head = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        char str[2];
        sprintf(str, "node%d", i);
        pushvar1(&head, str);
    }

    puts("Created Linked List: ");
    printListvar1(head);
    head = deleteList(head, 0, 2);
    puts("Linked list after deleted nodes from index 0 to index 2: ");
    printListvar1(head);
    freeList(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Test

```
Created Linked List: 
 node4  node3  node2  node1  node0 
Linked list after deleted nodes from index 0 to index 2: 
 node1  node0
```

Comment: What does the ? : mean in delete_at_index function?

Comment: @user6005857 `delete_at_index function` is a helper function that deletes one nore

Comment: I understand that. I was just confused with the question mark colon syntax but I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

every programming problem can be solved by adding an extra level of indirection: use a pointer to pointer ...

---

```
unsigned deletefromto(struct node **head, unsigned from, unsigned to)
{
unsigned pos,ret;
struct node *this;

for (pos=ret=0; this = *head;pos++) {
        if (pos < from) { head = &(*head)->next; continue; }
        if (pos > to) break;
        *head = this->next;
        free(this);
        ret++;
        }
return ret; /* nuber of deleted nodes */
}
```